# как передать значение select в PHP?

Tags: php, html, html-select

Если есть

```html
<select name="sel">
   <option value="1">один</option>
   <option value="2">два</option>
</select>
```

То для получения `value` нужно `$_POST["sel"]`. И я получу `1` или `2`, а как получить именно `text()`? Именно один или два?

Comment: напиши вместо 1 =>'один' . <option value="один">один</option>

Comment: Зачем?
Отправь ajaxом innerHTML тогда.

Comment: ну... тут то вопрос наверное про отправить форму ,скорее всего, поэтому без  использования js  через форму  только так..

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно вместо `1` указать в `value` то значение, которое хотите, чтобы передавалось в `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

Если есть другие поля в форме их нужно обработать отдельно.

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent From sending request
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  var sel = document.querySelector('select');
  // Text from the selected option
  var textSelected = sel.selectedOptions[0].text;
  console.log(textSelected);
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // Create form
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('sel', textSelected);
  // If you need more fields add them here
  // ....

  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // Send your form
  /**
  
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", "http://your-url");
  request.send(formData);
  
  ***/

})
```

```html
<form action="">
  <select name="sel">
    <option value="1">один</option>
    <option value="2">два</option>
  </select>
  <button type='submit'>Send</button>
</form>
```